# How to change the global proxy settings on Android devices in Gingerbread

Tags: android, proxy, android-2.3-gingerbread

I read the Android source code, and I am still confused about how to change the global proxy settings on devices.

It seems that `ProxySelectorImpl` just works for `HttpUrlConnection`. It then sets `Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY.RequestQuene`. `RequestQuene` will receive the proxy change broadcast and then call the method `setProxyConfig`. I don't know how `RequeneQuene` works in the network connection.

Can anyone tell me how Android handles different types of network requests and their proxies?